# Opening QGIS exported GML in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, qgis

I have exported a vector file in QGIS to GML format and now, Openlayers 3 cannot open that file and display it. 
I tried other things like ol.format.GML2() or ol.format.GML3(), but no help.
(OpenLayers can fetch that file from server, but does not displays it. It can display other layers with the same extent).

```
layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                title: 'myvector',
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    url: 'myvector.GML',     
                    format: new ol.format.GML()
                })
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried myself, and it looks like none of the GML flavours generated by QGIS is understood by OpenLayers. My suggestion would be to use GeoJSON instead, which is what I always do.

Comment: I also checked this link: http://converter.mygeodata.eu and it's GML output but no help. It sounds a problem with OpenLayers.

Comment: Thanks for reporting https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/5023. It might indeed be a problem with OpenLayers, but the generated GML looks strange. Let's wait for bartvde's assessment on the ticket.